# How to automatically adjust a photo (ie. brighten, contrast) on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My iOS app (objective-C) handles photos. I'd like it to be able offer the user a way to automatically "adjust" an image, like how iOS itself does in the Photos app (little magic-wand icon), or how facebook does it. This basically means auto-brightness and auto-contrast adjustment.

So far i've found "filtrr" (more concerned with adding color it seems), and OpenCV (uhh, feels like using a nuclear missile to swat a fly with). Any other hints? Is there some library or a way of even doing this natively in iOS?

thx!

Comment: Check the WWDC 2014 videos on updates to the CoreImage framework for some hints, the framework now works with full scale images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Look into Core Image for info on filters and how to apply them. [Apple's programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185) is a good place to start.
2. Once you're up and running with Core Image, see the [`autoAdjustmentFilters`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CIImage/autoAdjustmentFilters) method for getting a set of filters that's preconfigured for "one touch enhance" kinds of usage.